# Is my logo Plagiarism?

Tags: logo, plagiarism

[image]

I've been trying to design a logo for ages and have struggled to decide on one. Eventually, I gave up trying to design one myself and turned to Wix to help design one for me, which is just my company name in white on a black background. My problem is that I'm worried it looks very similar to other logos (as there are many out there that use the same concept). I also tried it with black writing on a white background but have the same problem. Would it be plagiarism to use either of these design concepts for my logo, or is it acceptable based on the fact that there are already multiple existing logos that are similar in the same way?

Comment: *"turned to Wix to help design one"* -- using a *template system* why would you expect anything more than a template which most likely will be similar to the template someone else chose? Wix is in the business of generating the same thing for thousands of customers. They **won't** focus on trying to be unique. They simply want to satiate you at the moment.

Comment: I don't think it can be considered "plagiarism" since it is so generic and non-styled that it's just "white text on black background". "Is it even a logo?" might be a better question. A logo should ideally be unique and make your customers remember your company. If you plan on using the logo to earn money you might consider investing in letting a graphic designer make one for you.